# Php dropdown change variable

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I have an HTML with GET to a php file. The HTML has dropdowns one of which is called Combobox8. What I want is that when a user selects ALL in dropdown the relative variable in php is set to all, if not it is set to the selection in the dropdown:

```
$shopfloor = if ($_GET['Combobox8'] <> "all") 
{ ($shopfloorvalue = $_GET['Combobox8'])} 
$shopfloorvalue='';
```

However I am getting an error.

What is wrong pls?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? Maybe try `!=` instead of `<>`.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If think you need some changes in your statement.

```
if($_GET['Combobox8'] != "all"){ 
    $shopfloorvalue = $_GET['Combobox8'];
} else {
    $shopfloorvalue='';
}
```

First of all you don't need to bind the if statement to a variable. If you want easy access to it bind it to a function instead!

```
function shoppingFloor(){
    if($_GET['Combobox8'] != "all"){ 
        $shopfloorvalue = $_GET['Combobox8']
    } else {
        $shopfloorvalue='';
    }
    return $shopfloorvalue;
}
```

then you can call it using `shoppingFloor()`.

Second you should try `!=` (is not) instead of `<>`.

If all you want is to simply bind the floor to `$shopfloorvalue` you can even try the short version of the if else.

`$shopfloorvalue = ($_GET['Combobox8'] != "all") ? $_GET['Combobox8'] : '';
                              ^                  ^                     ^
                       Your IF Statement  | if true what to do?  | Else what?  |`

Give it a try!

Comment: I tried it but I am getting an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\xampp\htdocs\tpm_dev\searchMaintenanceLogresultsdt.php on line 87. My code is :` function technamer(){
    if($_GET['Combobox10'] != "all"){ 
        $tech = $_GET['Combobox10']
    } else {
        $tech='';
    }
    return $tech;
} `

Comment: @elstiv That function is fine. It must be somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$shopfloor = ($_GET['Combobox8'] != "all") ? $_GET['Combobox8']:'';
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code from

```
$shopfloor = if ($_GET['Combobox8'] <> "all") 
{ ($shopfloorvalue = $_GET['Combobox8'])} 
$shopfloorvalue='';
```

To

```
$shopfloor = ($_GET['Combobox8'] <> "all")?$_GET['Combobox8']:'';
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$shopfloor = if ($_GET['Combobox8'] != "all")
```

{ ($shopfloorvalue = $_GET['Combobox8'])} 
$shopfloorvalue='';